# Printing isoceles triangle based on user input

Tags: java

I can make my code print out the proper amount of asterisks, but I need the asterisks in the "row" plane to increment only once each line. Here is the current code:

```
package isoceles;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Isoceles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int userSpecified;//this will be the userSpecified triangle side size
        int triangleSide;//printed triangle side size
        int width, height;
        
        System.out.print("Enter the size of equal sides for isoceles triangle: ");
        userSpecified = stdIn.nextInt();
        
        for (int col=1; col<=userSpecified; col++) 
        {
           for (int row=1; row<=userSpecified; row++) 
           {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
   }
}
```

With an input of four, the output will look like this:

```
^^^^
^^^^
^^^^
^^^^
```

The desired output is:

```
^
^^
^^^
^^^^
```

Comment: That is some funny looking JavaScript. Java is not JavaScript

Comment: Just a side note. The outer loop is generating the ROWS, while the inner loop is generating the COLUMNS.  Swap the names so it makes more "sense".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner-loop is wrong, instead of `row<=userSpecified`, it should be `row<=col`. Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Isoceles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int userSpecified;//this will be the userSpecified triangle side size
        int triangleSide;//printed triangle side size
        int width, height;
        
        System.out.print("Enter the size of equal sides for isoceles triangle: ");
        userSpecified = stdIn.nextInt();
        
        for (int col=1; col<=userSpecified; col++) 
        {
           for (int row=1; row<=col; row++) 
           {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```